# Haskell State monad and monadic guard

Tags: haskell, monadplus

i have small task to emulate imperative loop in monadic code with state involved and there should be no IO, the task is to exit loop on condition and here is my attempt:

```
> execState (forever $ modify (+1) >>= \x -> guard $ x < 5 ) 1
```

So i expect to get something like 4 here, but instead getting this cryptic message:

```
<interactive>:1:43:
    No instance for (MonadPlus Data.Functor.Identity.Identity)
      arising from a use of `guard' at <interactive>:1:43-47
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (MonadPlus Data.Functor.Identity.Identity)
    In the first argument of `($)', namely `guard'
    In the expression: guard $ x < 5
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `\ x -> guard $ x < 5'
```

Whole thing works ok without guard, but it seems completely hate guard for some reason.

**UPD**:
Finally i got it running, thanks to hammar for types hint. Despite it returns Nothing, i know it runs 5 times and this is cool, not sure how it can be useful for now.

```
runStateT (forever $ do { modify (+1); x <- get; guard $ x < 5 } :: StateT Int Maybe Int) 1
```

Comment: In what monad do you run this?

Comment: I talked about the monad inside execState.

Comment: It's actually '5' and you can get it if you swap transformers: `(\`execState\`1) . runMaybeT . forever $ do { modify (+1); x <- get; guard $ x < 5 }`

Comment: @Ed'ka it would be cool if you give type signatures for swapped variant, because i can not understand how haskell infers so complex type by its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message is trying to tell you, `guard` requires that the monad you're using must be an instance of the type class `MonadPlus`.

In this example, you're using the `State` monad, which is actually a `StateT` transformer on top of the `Identity` monad. There is a `MonadPlus` instance for `StateT`, but it requires that the underlying monad must be a `MonadPlus` as well, which `Identity` isn't.

For your example, you can try something like

```
> let loop = modify (+1) >> get >>= \x -> if x < 5 then loop else return x in execState loop 1
```

Comment: `modify (+1) :: (MonadState s m, Num s) => m ()`

So, you are passing () to the lambda, and trying to compare it to 5, which fails since () is not an instance of Num.

Comment: @pat: Thanks. Could've sworn `modify` returned the new value ;) I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not all monads support guard; only those in MonadPlus.  Looks like you're using the Identity monad (perhaps as part of execState).  What would you like to happen when the guard fails?

Comment: Hi, i expect when guard fails, then body loops until guard and when guard succeeds, then looping is finished